# how to stop all iron-list transitions being toggled - Polymer

Tags: jquery, html, css, polymer

I've been having trouble with an iron-list and triggering a transition of a panel coming in from right.

I have gotten the transition to work properly, however when I click on the settings icon for one particular row, ALL panels for all rows are triggered.

Any suggestions on how to solve that?

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<dom-module id="test-app-test">
  <template>
    <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
       :host {
        display: block;
      }

      .container {
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
      }

      .data:hover {
        background: lightgrey;
      }

      .data:last-child {
          border-bottom: none;
        }

        iron-list {
          background: white;
        }

        .icons {
          margin: 24px 16px 24px 16px;
        }

        .settings {
          padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
          margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
          width: 150px;
          height: 100%;
          background: grey;
          position: fixed;
          right: -160px;
          transition: transform 0.5s;
          color: white; 
        }

        .settingsMove {
          transform: translate(-140px);
        }

    </style>
      <iron-ajax url="data.json" last-response="{{data}}" auto ></iron-ajax>  
          <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="data" class="topList" selection-enabled >
              <template >

                    <div class="container horizontal layout">
                      <paper-icon-button class="icons" icon="settings" on-click="toggleSettings"></paper-icon-button>
                      <div class="settings">
                        <paper-icon-button icon="delete"></paper-icon-button>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="create"></paper-icon-button>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" on-click="toggleSettings"></paper-icon-button>
                      </div>
                    </div>              
              </template>
        </iron-list>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'test-app-test',

      properties: {

      },

      toggleSettings : function() {
          $('.settings').removeClass('settingsMove');
          $(this).toggleClass('settingsMove');
      },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f6dvbpx6/

Comment: and by the way.. DON'T USE JQUERY in Polymer elements inner functions, Polymer already provides a lot of implemented function to manipulate the element you create. This is so useless.

Comment: and by the way.. DON'T USE JQUERY in Polymer elements inner functions, Polymer already provides a lot of implemented function to manipulate the element you create. This is so useless.

Comment: and by the way.. DON'T USE JQUERY in Polymer elements inner functions, Polymer already provides a lot of implemented function to manipulate the element you create. This is so useless.

Comment: Thanks for the super-constructive advice there @ballangddang... An example of how to overcome my lacking knowledge in the field would have been much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `toggleSettings` find all elements with `settings` class which is wrong behavior. You need to select only 1 element( parent of button propably? your code doesn't make sense). To do this, update your function:

```
 toggleSettings : function(e) {
      this.toggleClass("settingsMove", false, e.target.parentElement);
      this.toggleClass("settingsMove", true, e.target);
 },
```

I am using Polymer function `toggleClass` because it seems to me much more better than Jquery which isn't really required in Polymer projects. Plus word `this` doesn't work like you expect. It doesn't point to current clicked element but to host element. (whole `test-app-test`)

Propably something like this? I have no idea what you are trying, because your code really doesn't make sense to me. You are trying to find element with class `settings` and on this element, remove class `settingsMove` ? and then on `paper-icon-button` set class `settingsMove` ?

What you want to achiev ? when user presses button, one specific row is hidden from view?